# What is a Rack - "no acceptor" error?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin

While trying to run my config.ru, I'm getting an odd error I can't seem to debug called a 'No acceptor' error.

Full error message:

```
eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
```

Does anyone know what this error means? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Fivell says, I think the problem is that you have a previous instance of `thin` still running. Rather than start on another port though, I would recommend killing the previous instance. Something like this should do the job (I recreated the problem here, so this is real output on my end):

```
telemachus caps $ ps ax | grep ruby
  153   ??  S      7:52.18 ruby /usr/local/bin/djsd
15801   ??  S      0:00.40 ruby caps.rb  # this is our problem, get it's PID
15973 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep ruby

telemachus caps $ kill -9 15801 # thin needs -9 - hard to kill
telemachus caps $ ps ax | grep ruby
  153   ??  R      7:52.86 ruby /usr/local/bin/djsd
16057 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep ruby
```

Depending on how you started your app, you may need to `grep` for something different (say if you used `shotgun` or `rackup`).

Comment: Yup, it was a server that bailed, a reboot of my computer fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that using port is already binded (maybe you started your application earlier) Try to change port

```
rackup config.ru -p port    #default port is 9292 change to something else
```

or if you use thin

```
thin start  -p port -a 0.0.0.0  -R config.ru #default port is 8080 change to something else
```

Comment: I've seen this exact problem a number of times when people simply shut a terminal window instead of using `CTRL-C` to kill a running thin server. If you close the window, the process seems to go zombie.

Comment: I personally did it few days ago =)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error although there are no zombie processes and the port is not binded.

This works:

```
thin -p9292 start
```

But this does not:

```
rackup
```